# Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type" magento via Dataflow Profile error

Tags: magento-1.8

Why does my import csv through Import->Dataflow profiles throw the below error?

```
Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type"
```

The same product csv uploads via System->Import/Export->Import, but not with Dataflow profiles.

1) My catalog_product_entity table is empty

2) I have **_type** as a column in csv

Comment: better option is to use magmi : http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page ....

Answer (score 1):

Try to download product csv using `System > Import/Export > Data - Profiles`.

Than select `Export All Products`.

And Specify `SKU` under `Export Filter`.

Click `Save and Coutinue Edit`.

After That Click `Run Profile` from the Left side.

Click the `Run Profile in Popup`.

Now you have Data Profile CSV according to this you can change CSV and Upload it as per your option.

Comment: I have no data in my table @Learning Phase, i cant export

Comment: Than try to add new product from backend and than download CSV. because CSV format is different as per simple import/export

Comment: have you got solution ? @SachinS

Answer (score 0):

Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type" error can signal that you do not have values for product type in the import file. Since you are using traditional export/import method, some column heading could be exported in human readable format. Check whether your column name does not start with underscore in the import file, for example '_type'. 
If you want to use export/import scenario often to update your product details, you should better find some extension for flexible import/export on [www.magentocommerce.com](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/), for example this [magento-manager](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/store-manager-for-magento-professional-edition-1.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are going to create new items, the type column should be named "type", not "_type", and make sure there are values in this column.
2. If you are going to update some info for items, this error means, there is some SKU in your importing CSV file that doesn't exist in the database of Magento.

When you are importing a CSV file into Magento, Magento will judge if the item is new by SKU. If the SKU doesn't exist before, it will create a new item of this SKU, but "type" is a required field. If the SKU has existed already, Magento will update the information you provided in the CSV file.

In conclusion:
 if (SKU is new && type is blank) 
    {error: Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type"}

; )